# Using Azure websites, but what about a web mail solution

Tags: azure, cloud, imap, webmail

Have played about with windows azure for a little while and i am quite fond of it, however a common requirement with most web sites is to provide a web mail and POP / IMAP solution like you get with the traditional shared web hosting from godaddy.

As anybody got any solutions for this,  i am after a way to provide customers that have a domain a web mail platform with  POP and IMAP access.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at SendGrid? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/

Comment: I did take a look but isn't that just SMTP/ send only

Comment: Yes it is - you might have to look at setting up Google Apps or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Updated: Outlook.com no longer offers support for custom domain management. New customers looking to manage custom domains are
>   encouraged to use Office 365** Not working with custom domain: [https://www.domains.live.com](https://domains.live.com/) anymore. Working but not free: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/migrate-custom-domain

<del>Live Custom Domains service from Microsoft.**
It is **free service** on your **own** (customer) **domain**. You can set **CNAME**, eg. mail.yourdomain.com. You will obtain **POP3, IMAP, EAS** with a new **Outlook.com** look & feel.</del>

For accessing account using POP3 or IMAP in your **email client software**: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app

Also you'll get **SkyDrive** cloud storage for **free**: http://skydrive.com/

**Microsoft** has a good documented **API** for it here: http://isdk.dev.live.com/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx

As **SMTP** server with huge traffic you can use SendGrid, up to **200 mails per a day** is also **free**.
http://sendgrid.com/pricing.html

**SendGrid** has nice statistics and categorization functionality with it's very powerful **API**: http://sendgrid.com/docs/

Comment: Wow, perfect. I Have to say Microsoft have really impressed me with their free offerings, WebsiteSpark with free Widodows Azure Credits and all the software. TFS in the cloud for 5 users for free and now this....

Comment: Note that you'll need to enable POP access for **email client software**: *Log in to Webmail > Settings > More email settings > Connect devices and app with POP > Enable*

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23153554/4525), (which has an open bounty as of this writing), according to which the first option here is going away.

Comment: This option *has* now gone away: `"Outlook.com no longer offers support for custom domain management."`. Time to find a new solution :(