# Microsoft Azure Websites - Custom domain mail

Tags: email, azure

Microsoft Live Custom Domains are now shutting down. I have been using this service for e-mail hosting for all my Microsoft Azure Websites, but now it is gone and no viable replacement is in sight. Do you have some idea what alternative approach exist for hosting multiple mailboxes for multiple websites hosted on Azure?

Comment: Would be interested to understand a bit more about how you utilise custom domains along with your websites - are they to receive mail from the website or are they they to receive emails sent directly from users of the websites?  Note that Live custom domains are deprecated but will continue to work - you just can't add new ones or new mailboxes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I feel your pain. Had to have some tough talks with many of my customers when the free Google Apps option was discontinued.

I found two routes:

1. Find a hosted Exchange type solution. This has the advantages of any hosted solution. It is managed for you. You can get started with around 50 USD / user / year and services are provided by the likes of Microsoft, Google and Rackspace, like stated in the other answers.
2. (Which is the route I chose) Host your own Exchange server on AWS EC2 or Azure. Thanks to Microsoft License Mobility, you can install an Exchange license on a cloud server and provide email addresses for your customers` domains yourself. This will allow you to share the cost of the Exchange license between all your customers and if you reach the critical mass, this can save a lot compared to the pay-per-user-per-month models for most hosted solutions.

I am stil looking for a free alternative, but have yet to find one that can match the features that were available in the free version of Google Apps.

**EDIT:** I was thinking about this again last night and came up with another idea. I am not a Linux guy, so I would not be happy to do this for production mail server. For someone who is "bilingual" (i.e. ok with both MS and Linux solutions) or of a more adventurous nature than me, could take route 2 with a linux server and an open source mail server solution. I am sure this will lower the cost even more significantly, since you will not need to pay for the mail server licence and also per-hour instance costs for Linux servers are lower. This might even create a whole new revenue stream.

Comment: I am grappling with the same question and option 2 would be my preferred choice too. But from what I have read, hosting an email server on Azure was ruled out on account of the Azure IP ranges getting blacklisted by spammers. Would you mind sharing your experience so far?

Comment: Per my previous comment, see [this question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/478076/can-an-email-server-be-set-up-on-an-azure-vm)

Comment: @MattJenkins - I am using AWS personally. I think AWS has a more diverse set of IPs + it`s less accessible than Azure (in this case, may be a good thing). I have not had issue thus far, but as the guy on SF says, this might not be guaranteed. If it happens, I might transfer to a less known host. Where I host is less of an issue for me. Cloud services are great for many things, but not a must in this specific case.

Answer (score 26):

Your cheapest option is to have one (single) google apps account which will cost you around $5 per month.   Make it something very general like mail@yourdomain.com.    Then in the google apps dashboard make it a catch all address.  This will make the single inbox catch all email for accounts such as Sales@, support@ bob@ or whatever at your domain.

Then you can set Gmail filters to sort (label) each incomming message based on who it was sent to.  For example you can have messages sent to frank@ automatically labeled as frank.

Next you want to create regular old gmail accounts for all of your individual users.  I am going to follow the example of creating a box for frank@company.com for this instance.

1. Create Google Apps primary account (catch all) as mail@company.com
2. Create Gmail account for frank.company@gmail.com (regular gmail account)
3. Create filter rule on Google Apps account for all messages sent to frank@company.com to be forwarded to frank.company@gmail.com.  You can further mark them as read or delete them upon forward.
4. In the frank.company@gmail.com create a sending alias as frank@company.com.  Google will give you a 4 digit code, and now when logging in as frank.company@gmail.com i can both send as frank@company.com and recieve all email since its forwarded to this account.

Also make sure to set default reply:to addresses in case you send from the frank.company@gmail.com address.

Using the technique above you can get all the benefits of having a pro google apps account (dkim, spf, 25gb inbox) and with a little bit of configuration you can setup multiple gmail accounts which run off the single account.   We use the technique above and it works flawlessly.  The only thing that doesn't work is mailbox delegation, which is not that great.

If you wanted to save the $5 you could get away with using something like GoDaddy free email forwarding, but then you would be limited to godaddys 250 message limit per day.

The approach above just works.

Comment: Great Hack Frank!

Comment: i will try this. Thank's.

Answer (score 6):

Zoho provides a Google Apps like deal for 5 users for free:
https://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html

- Up to five users
- 5GB/User
- 25MB attachment limit
- Web access only
- Email hosting for single domain

Answer (score 5):

I just finished installing a mail server in Azure in a Linux virtual machine. So far seems ok.

The total cost of operation is about 10€ a month since neither Ubuntu (the OS) nor iredMail (the mail server) nor Postgres (the database) have any licensing fees.

Regarding the block on Azure IPs I do believe that most users saying that did not correctly configured their servers. And by that I mean that they didn't configured the PTR reverse DNS on Azure, which allows other mail servers to check if that IP is allowed to send and receive mail from that domain.

Also make sure you add the SPF DNS entry for your mail server. You can't blame a mail server to blacklist you if you don't minimize the risks of SPAM.

Hope this helped you.

Useful links:
IredMail Server - http://www.iredmail.org/

Reverse DNS in Azure - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to identify how much and what all services do you need?

1. If it is just an IMAP/POP3 Email Box, then best option is a Virtual Server or Virtual Machine with cpanel, once installed with daily backup runs good for years, you get unlimited email accounts and unlimited space !!! You can increase your VM dynamically up when you need it. Drawback is, it takes little maintenance once in a while. But most likely cpanel auto update is very stable and I have VPS running for 5 years and every year we are just increasing our disk space.
2. If you want calendar along with live docs editing etc, then you have to go with Google Apps which is cheaper then MS Exchange. But if you need strict Exchange kind of services, then you will have to go with hosted Exchange.
3. I will not recommend spending money for Rackspace or any such Cloud Email which is priced per user, which is total waste of money as they do not offer anything apart from linux server with cpanel. Those services are only for non IT people. Since you have already asked question on Stack Overflow, you can easily setup and manage cpanel based linux OS.

Answer (score 2):

you could run a Ubuntu VM in Azure and set up Postfix

Comment: Its kind of a pain even with shell scripts to get everything going.  You still have to figure out PostFix, plus MySQL for users, plus virus scanning, and some sort of imap option (cyrus or whatever).  Even then you just get a mail server and have to figure out calendar, and contacts.  I have gone over this 1000s times, and always came back feeling getting the open source options is way too time consuming.

Comment: I agree with you.  it's not for the faint of heart, and depending on your use case, may entail a lot of maintenance.  have you considered Office 365? it may be a bit pricey (compared to free) but it's a pretty complete solution

Answer (score 2):

You can install a Free Mail Server on a Virtual Machine on Azure like:

https://www.hmailserver.com/download

Answer (score 1):

I have found the same problem myself.

The only alternative in the past would have been to use Google's equivalent service, but they have also stopped it.

Realistically, there isn't a free answer to using custom domains with emails that I am aware of. Both Microsoft and Google offer paid for services, but cost per user/mailbox, per-year - compared to their free services this is a big jump in price.

Google charge £33 per user/mailbox, per year.
Microsoft are slightly dearer at £39 per user/mailbox, per year, but include access to online versions of Office for each user too.

For my situation, the Microsoft route may be the better option, based on my customer preferences but I am sure that the Google service is equally adequate.

Hope this helps. (But let me know if you find a better alternative!!!)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'm aware that these solutions exist, but I'm still hoping the some cheaper way is possible. We will see :-) .

Answer (score 1):

How many real people do you have reading e-mail? As many as you got mailboxes? If not, then I really suggest you go for Exchange Online from Microsoft which goes for $4 per user (not mailbox) per month.

The trick is, that once you've set up your domains, you create a `Shared Mailbox` through PowerShell and while doing so, you give the real people (you pay for) the rights to read and `send as`. The cool thing is, that the user does not need to do anything. The mailbox simply appears in their Outlook.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but unfortunately for my scenario it is basically a user for each mailbox...